# Pyspark intersection

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking to get the intersection of two RDDs in `pyspark`. They look like the following:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(["abc","def", "ghi"])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([["abc","123"],["df",345], ["ghi","678"])
```

Is it possible using pyspark's rdd operators to get:

```
intersection_rdd --> ["abc","123"] ["ghi","678"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick approach via PySpark RDD is to use `join` but note that it requires the two RDDs to be the same size.  To do this, we will start with your example below

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([["abc"],["def"], ["ghi"]])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([["abc", 123],["df", 345], ["ghi", 678]])
```

You can then create `rdd1a` so its the same size as `rdd2`.

```
rdd1a = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0], 1))
```

And then you can run `join`:

```
rdd1a.join(rdd2).map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][1])).collect()
## Out[25]: [('abc', 123), ('ghi', 678)]
```

Note, this may not be the performant approach for large RDDs but its a quick and fast way for getting this out.

Another approach would be to utilize `DataFrames` per below:

```
df1 = rdd1.toDF(['col'])
df2 = rdd2.toDF(['col', 'value'])
df_intersect = df1.join(df2, df1.col == df2.col, 'inner').select(df1.col, df2.value)
df_intersect.show()
```

with the output being:

```
+---+-----+
|col|value|
+---+-----+
|ghi|  678|
|abc|  123|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You will try this to solve your problem:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([[x] for x in ["abc","def", "ghi"]])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([["abc","123"],["df",345], ["ghi","678"]])    
df1 = rdd1.toDF(['key'])
df2 = rdd2.toDF(['key', 'value'])
intersect = df1.join(df2, 'key').orderBy('key')
intersect.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|abc|  123|
|ghi|  678|
+---+-----+
```